# Embedding Python in AHK(I have a code from AHK website), can't I put multiple python script in one Autohotkey script?

Tags: python, autohotkey

Embedding Python in AHK(I have a code from AHK website), can't I put multiple python script in one Autohotkey script?

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=7732

Python code is embeded with parenthesis, and it works fine. Like,

```
py =
(
some code
some code
)
Runpython(py) : works fine

Runpython()
{
some code
some code
}
```

Yes, codes above works fine. But what I am having trouble with is,
if I have more than one python codes like below, it seems like to return only the first python script no matter how.

```
py1 =
(
some code
some code
)

py2 =
(
some code
some code
)

Runpython(py1) ; returns py1 which is fine 

Runpython(py2) ; still returns py1, which is the trouble I got.

Runpython()
{
some code
some code
}
```

Yes, it is like above. Hope I can run py2 as well as py1.

Comment: Maybe try concatenating the Python code before sending it to `Runpython`?

Comment: I acually solved this one via modifying some dllcall commands inside. The thing was runpython() has DllCall(PythonDll1 "\Py_Finalize", "Cdecl"). After cutting out that line, it works like a charm.

Comment: It would be useful to write up an answer to your own question (click on the blue "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom), so that later in the future if someone encounters the same problem, you can help them with your answer.

Comment: Yeah I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the link up there, there is a script far below which was completed by the user named XeroByte.
And I put that here in a shortened form to contain crutial parts only.

I wanted to run multiple python scripts. But everytime I tried to run the second script, the first one was run always.
I decided to take out each line until it works.

```
pyStr= ;python code
(
Some code works
Some code works 
)

pyStr2= ;python code that I added
(
Some code don't work
Some code don't work
)

RunPython(pyStr:="", PyVer:="")

    finalPyStr := (pyStr="") ? Selection() : pyStr ; if a string has been passed into this function then use that as the python code, otherwise use the currently selected text using my custom Selection() function
    if(StrLen(finalPyStr) > 0){ ; Only do the following if there is some python code to run
        DllCall("LoadLibrary", "Str", PythonDll)
        DllCall(PythonDll "\Py_Initialize", "Cdecl")
        DllCall(PythonDll "\PyRun_SimpleString", "AStr", finalPyStr)
        DllCall(PythonDll "\Py_Finalize", "Cdecl")
    }
    return 1
}
```

Finally, I learned that `DllCall(PythonDll "\Py_Finalize", "Cdecl")` was the main problem. I don't know its use exactly, but it definitely blocked my second script to be run. So the final form is as follows.

```
pyStr= ;python code
(
Some code works
Some code works 
)

pyStr2= ;python code that I added
(
Some code works
Some code works
)

RunPython(pyStr:="", PyVer:="")

    finalPyStr := (pyStr="") ? Selection() : pyStr ; if a string has been passed into this function then use that as the python code, otherwise use the currently selected text using my custom Selection() function
    if(StrLen(finalPyStr) > 0){ ; Only do the following if there is some python code to run
        DllCall("LoadLibrary", "Str", PythonDll)
        DllCall(PythonDll "\Py_Initialize", "Cdecl")
        DllCall(PythonDll "\PyRun_SimpleString", "AStr", finalPyStr)
    }
    return 1
}
```

And my second code also works as first one.

Comment: Nice work! Make sure to click the checkmark on the left of your answer to show that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Wasn't aware of what it was, thanks for letting me know. Cheers!

Comment: I think you only need to call `Py_Finalize` once your script actually exits and doesn't need the python dll anymore. Likely it frees up some resources.